# Dynamic Radio Button CheckedChanged event won't fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, dynamic-controls

I am creating two radio buttons dynamically with C# but the CheckedChange event isn't firing. I am using the following code:

```
RadioButton enable = new RadioButton();
enable.ID = "enable";
enable.Text = "Enable";
enable.GroupName = "enableDisableGroup";
enable.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(enableRadioButton_CheckedChanged);

RadioButton disable = new RadioButton();
disable.ID = "disable";
disable.Text = "Disable";
disable.GroupName = "enableDisableGroup";
disable.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(disableRadioButton_CheckedChanged);

UpdatePanel upEnableDisable = new UpdatePanel();
upEnableDisable.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;
upEnableDisable.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(enable);
upEnableDisable.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(disable);

AsyncPostBackTrigger enableTrigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
enableTrigger.ControlID = enable.ID;
enableTrigger.EventName = "CheckedChanged";
upEnableDisable.Triggers.Add(enableTrigger);
AsyncPostBackTrigger disableTrigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
disableTrigger.ControlID = disable.ID;
disableTrigger.EventName = "CheckedChanged";
upEnableDisable.Triggers.Add(disableTrigger);

mainDiv.Controls.Add(upEnableDisable);
```

After creating the radio buttons, I am associating the `Checked Changed` event with them. Then I am putting these inside an UpdatePanel. I also tried to create two `AsyncPostBackTrigger`s but that didn't work either. Can you please tell me what can be the problem with the code snippet provided above?

Comment: I think you have to go with registering the AsyncPostBackTrigger for the checkchanged events. But you have tried this already right?

Comment: Yes yes you can see it in the code above. `enableTrigger.EventName = "CheckedChanged";`

Comment: try to set AutoPostBack="true" for you radionbuttons!

Answer (score 2):

```
RadioButton enable = new RadioButton();
enable.ID = "enable";
enable.Text = "Enable";
enable.AutoPostBack = true;
enable.GroupName = "enableDisableGroup";
enable.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(enableRadioButton_CheckedChanged);

RadioButton disable = new RadioButton();
disable.ID = "disable";
disable.Text = "Disable";
disable.AutoPostBack = true;
disable.GroupName = "enableDisableGroup";
disable.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(disableRadioButton_CheckedChanged);

UpdatePanel upEnableDisable = new UpdatePanel();
upEnableDisable.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;
upEnableDisable.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(enable);
upEnableDisable.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(disable);

AsyncPostBackTrigger enableTrigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
enableTrigger.ControlID = enable.ID;
enableTrigger.EventName = "CheckedChanged";
upEnableDisable.Triggers.Add(enableTrigger);
AsyncPostBackTrigger disableTrigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
disableTrigger.ControlID = disable.ID;
disableTrigger.EventName = "CheckedChanged";
upEnableDisable.Triggers.Add(disableTrigger);

mainDiv.Controls.Add(upEnableDisable);
```